# How to write tests for child of abstract class? Rails expects a table name to be specified for the parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two related classes:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  ...
end
class B < A
  ...
end
```

I want to test that class B can be created:

```
class BTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "can create B" do
    record = B.create!
    assert record.valid?
  end
end
```

However it seems like the test suite does not understand that A is an abstract class. It gives me the following error:

```
BTest#test_can_create_b:
ActiveRecord::TableNotSpecified: A has no table configured. Set one with A.table_name=
    /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:577:in `load_schema!'
```

I tried adding A.table_name=nil in the model file.
I tried adding A.abstract_class=true in the test file.

Comment: I cannot recreate this issue [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/WirelessContentHypercard). Are you certain the question is identical to your existing setup? Maybe a full stack trace would help us track this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a leftover `as.yml` fixture in your `test/fixtures`, so the test suite is trying to populate that and throwing the error.